# emails sent with "send object" macro sometimes get stuck in Outlook outbox

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2007 macro that uses the send object command to send emails with an HTML attachment. My problem is that around 20% of these emails get stuck in the Outlook outbox. For some unknown reason, the "delay delivery" checkbox in Outlook is automaticaly checked off to delay the delivery, for these emails.  I dont know if this is relevant, but I use the app "Click Yes",  in order to automatically authorize Outlook to send the messages.  Please advise what I can do in order not to expereince the emails from getting stuck in the Outbox
THank you very much, Nathaniel

Answer (score 0):

SendObject is not very versatile. To control these things you likely have to automate Outlook, which has its own set of complications. See [Tony Toews's Email FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/email.htm).